# selenium to check the appearance of some elements everytime reloading the page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need reload a page again and again in order to get the newly updated content . I use selenium to do the job, but I am new to it, so encountered the following difficulties:

1. After  reloading the page each time,  the page **sometimes** just show
   me a dialog with captcha image, which requires me to input the right
   captcha code to proceed. I have used [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) of Selenium Webdriver to wait for the appearance of the dialog right now, if the dialog appear, then get the captcha image recognized and send the captcha code back to proceed, but this dialog monitor precedure only takes effect the first time I load the page, it didn't work for  the page reloading, so how to make the  dialog monitor procedure work everytime the page is reloaded?
2. then check if a specific element is visible , then perform some clicks
   on it and get data from there. I also need this procedure work everytime the page is reloaded, so how?
3. Reload the page.

The following is a code example , I want the `try-except-else` block and `tryToGetDataFromElement()` run everytime the page is reloaded, so how?

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
chromeOptions.add_argument("start-maximized")
chromeOptions.binary_location = r"C:\Users\i\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chromeOptions)
driver.get('https://oversea.csair.com/new/us/zh/flights?m=0&p=100&flex=0&t=LAX-CAN-20200802_LAX');

try: 
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ('#captcha-box img, #cabin_0_0_FFF')))
    )
except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
    driver.refresh() 

else:
    deCaptcha()

tryToGetDataFromElement()
```

Comment: You have a good description in your question, but without a [repro] we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another mentioned, it is hard without being able to reproduce but [here](https://gist.github.com/nebula1989/a079e479d6094182df423a95f8a928a7) is some psuedo code that may help.

You could just skip the captcha if it doesn't appear, instead of trying to force to captcha to appear, which I don't know how to do.  If you can include the link that you're working on that will help.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I forgot about the `while True` loop in this case,   and I added my psuedo code in the question description.